# The set of differentiability of an extension from half-plane to the plane

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives, examples-counterexamples

This question is related to: [Differentiability: Partially Defined Functions](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/875288/79762)

Consider a real-valued function $f:\mathbb{H}^2\to\mathbb{R}$.

[image: Differentiability (Extension)]

Are there some that admit no extension differentiable in more than one boundary point?
$$a\in\partial\mathbb{H}^2:\quad f_E:U_a\to\mathbb{R}$$

Comment: Are you planning to answer this one?  If not, did you have thoughts on the problem?

Comment: No, I thought about it but couldn't get any further. Besides it is similar to but not exactly like Schwarz's reflection principle. Do you have an idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The function $f(x,y)=y\sqrt{x}$, originally defined in the right  halfplane, can be extended  as a function differentiable at $(0,0)$, but no extension is differentiable at other points of the $y$-axis.

Comment: Great thanks!! :)

Comment: Now, do you think there is also a function that has for every point separately an extension differentiable at that point but no common extension differentiably at all boundary points simultaneously?

Comment: That is a rather different question. I suspect that the answer is no, and the [Whitney extension theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Whitney_extension_theorem) may be useful.

Comment: By no do you mean _"no, every function then also admits a common extension"_ or do you mean _"no, there are functions which admit no common extension"_?

Comment: I mean: if there is a differentiable extension for every point, there should be one for all points at once.